# need help to find the duplicate element in a list in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

```
import csv
import re
from collections import Counter
with open('articles.txt',encoding="ANSI") as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
line_count = 0
author = []
#publication = []
#for row in csv_reader:
    #publication += [[row[3]]]
for row in csv_reader:
    author += [[row[4]]]
count = 0
NPR_list=[]
for number in range(1,len(new_file)):
    if 'NPR'== str(new_file[number][3]):
       NPR_list.append(author[number])
       count+= 1
for remove in range(1,273):
    NPR_list.remove([''])
list(NPR_list)     
print(NPR_list)
Counter(NPR_list).mostcommon(5)
```

It will return an error, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
how do I change the code to make it return the top 5 duplicate elements?
Thank you

Comment: Please share an example of your source data file.

Answer (score 0):

your error is because of your `author` variable is a list of lists, here is an example:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter([[1], [2]])
```

output:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

you do not need to store in the `author` elements as lists, you have to change this line: `author += [[row[4]]]` with `author += [row[4]]` or `author.append(row[4])`